# Salesforce debug logs in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, salesforce, apex-code, apex

Is there any way to view Salesforce debug logs in eclise ide? 
I tried to do some preliminary search but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Hi @Sven, looks like you already got an answer to this, but wanted to let you know there is a new stackexchange site specific to Salesforce at salesforce.stackexchange.com. Come join the community over there! :)  As a reference there are about 4 times as many questions on the new stackexchange compared to SO, and a lot more active users.

Comment: you are right Ralph.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can receive debug log in Eclipse only, if you run apex tests or execute anonymous code from Eclipse. In other cases you can find debug logs in Setup->Logs->Debug or in Developer Console.